# creating mysql db from exported sql with php exec

Tags: php, mysql, sql, exec

All I want to do is create a new database off of a dump created by phpmyadmin.
This dump is located in : /var/www/iadmin/wikifresh/db/template.sql and won't ever change.

I ran this command once, and the database was created fine

```
mysql test < /var/www/iadmin/wikifresh/db/template.sql
```

and it created the database. So, I put that script inside of a php exec command:
(note: $wikiname is the name of the new wiki being created)

```
$dbwikiname = escapeshellarg($wikiname);
exec("mysql $dbwikiname < /var/www/iadmin/wikifresh/db/template.sql");
```

now, when this script runs, I get:

```
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'test'
```

even if I try to run it from my command line I have this issue.

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `mysql` to be invoked with a default database name, the database must exist.

Some distributions of MySQL happen to ship with a database called `test`, which explains why your command succeeded at first.  One presumes you have since dropped that database?  You will need to recreate it before attempting to select it:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test;
```

Of course, you could instead place the above command, followed by `USE test;` atop your `template.sql` file and then invoke `mysql` without specifying a default database.

Comment: That works great, thank you, how would I run the import script then? Right now I have:
mysql --user=uname --password=pword -e "testing < /var/scriptpath/template.sql"

I'm getting a syntax error

Answer (score 1):

it seems you don't have the database 'test' created in the MySQL server of that machine, and the template.sql doesn't have the 'CREATE DATABASE' command. So you have to either create it first, or add the 'CREATE DATABASE' to the template.sql